# dojo.xhrpost getting status code as 0

Tags: ajax, dojo

I am submitting a for using dojo's xhrpost. My app runs on ruby on rails. In the controller I am performing a redirect. I store the redirected URL the response headers. I access the redirected URL on the client and then load the redirected URL on the client. The following is the code.

In the view, performing ajax submit using dojo.xhrpost

```
         function () {
         var form = dojo.byId("form_id");

         dojo.connect(form, "onsubmit", function(event){
          // Stop the submit event since we want to control form submission.
          dojo.stopEvent(event);

          var xhrArgs = {
            form: dojo.byId("form_id"),
            handleAs: "text",
            load: function(data, ioargs){
            //getting redirected url from response header
             var new_url = ioargs.xhr.getResponseHeader("new_url");

             //redirecting to the url  
             document.location.href = new_url;
            },
            error: function(response){
            //handling error
            }
         }

          //submitting for to action1 of controller
         var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
      });
    }
```

Code in controller

```
        def action1
          new_url = url_for(:controller=>"controller", :action => "action2")
          #passing the new URL as parameter in the redirection
          redirect_to :action2, :new_url => new_url
        end

        def action2
          #getting the new url from the params and saving it in respone header so that it can be accesses in client
          response.headers["new_url"] = params[:new_url]
        end
```

This worked fine on my local host. But when I put it on my server its failing.
I am getting the ioargs.xhr.status as "0". data is " ". Though the form is getting saved response is empty and no response headers are getting set. 
Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to modify the controller a bit.

```
def action1
  if request.xhr?
    render :json => new_url.to_json
  else
  #follow normal redirection
  redirect_to :action2
end
```

Also in the ajax call

```
var xhrArgs = {
        form: dojo.byId("form_id"),
        handleAs: "json",
        load: function(data, ioargs){
        //getting redirected url from data 
         document.location.href = data;
        },
        error: function(response){
        //handling error
        }
```

Basically I found out returning the entire HTML page as response in not the right way.

Only the URL should be returned in the response and redirection should be done from the View,